# Can I call a search help programatically, with some parameters already filled in and non-editable?

Tags: search, abap, sap-data-dictionary

I have collective search help `S_MAT1` defined for data element `MATNR`.

I want to invoke programatically the append search help `S_MAT1_APPEND`, this means that when I press a button in an ALV list, I have to trigger a search dialog, like that for a search help.

I'd also want to be able to fill in some parameters automatically, and not let the user change those.

I am expecting to find a function module that does this.
`HELP_START` doesn't seem too documented, and doesn't seem to be what I want.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Use the function module `F4IF_GET_SHLP_DESCR` to get a description of the search help, then call `F4IF_START_VALUE_REQUEST` with the description data. Be aware that you need to set `SHLP-INTERFACE-VALFIELD` to `X` for the fields you want to get back from the value help.

Comment: yes... well.. apparently that's exactly what I eventually did :) Good to have a confirmation from pros though